# Stop VC++ from pointing at errors in files outside my project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

Is there any way to make VC++ 2010 trace errors back to the last line that was called INSIDE my project?

I don't know why they did it, but its completely useless when VC++ tells me that the error is inside one of the standard classes rather than which line in my project actually led to that error.

Comment: You mean with Intellitrace or in normal debugging? Can't you just use the call stack?

Comment: normal debugging. Its pointing at "void __cdecl _unlock" in "mlock.c" which means absolutely nothing..if you mean the Stack Frame dropdown, I don't see any of my own functions in there

Comment: I meant the Call Stack window (Debug, Windows, Call Stack) but yes that'll show the same list. It sounds like you've triggered an error before or after your program has run, then, or you've caused problems on another thread. When do you get the error? Does the Thread dropdown show Main Thread or something else? You may have corrupted some memory somewhere and the debugger can't easily tell you when that happened.

Comment: Its a single threaded webserver. When I try to load a page, I get the error. There are a couple of different procedures listed, and "Line (x) + 0xNN bytes" which still isn't really enough..it would still leave me sifting through code manual, adding breakpoints and so forth to check each value along the way one by one

Comment: see, I got lucky and found it, and that it was a "<" instead of a ">" somewhere in my code...but VS was completely useless in helping me find that error =/

Comment: VS didn't tell me though, which array was reading or writing out of bounds...It has to be as easy as stopping at a breakpoint for VC++ to point to the last line executed INSIDE my project before the error occured...there must be a way to do it

Answer (score 0):

from the main menu debug->windows->call stack

Comment: I see Debug->Windows, but the menu contains no entry called "Call Stack" =/ Basically what I want is for asserts to point to the actual line with the code assert(something) rather than inside assert.h